# How to implement Google’s Search index for an restricted site?

Tags: search, search-engine, google-search, google-search-api

I am trying to index a fully authenticated site which is not open to anonymous users in Google’s Search index.

But, As per my understandings, the service ‘First Click Free’ from Google to include relevant content in Google’s Search index will work on few basic conditions like

-> User who came from google search result should be shown with the full content of the current page without asking for registration or payment or login

-> Google crawler won’t work on the pages which are behind registration or login pages.

In such cases how should i process further ?

Example : If my site www.example.com/article is an restricted article listing page which will be shown to the authenticated users alone, How should i process with Google's Search Indexing?

-> So that if I search for "articles in example.com", I need to get www.example.com/article in google's search result.

-> If a user clicks on the search result link he should be taken to www.example.com/article page if his session is already running.

-> If his session is not active he should be asked to login as the site is already doing that.

Can anybody suggest some ideas for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope ip_login(https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_login) module will help to crawl the restricted pages.